# How to create a custom query in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to make a custom query with inner join and display the name instead of the id of that table

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('chriscrudBundle:BpCrpCard')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find BpCrpCard entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('chriscrudBundle:BpCrpCard:show.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb->select('bp.name')
->innerJoin('bp.phones', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.id'  =           'bp.id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create some custom queries in your repositories thanks to DQL:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

You can also do raw SQL this way:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT foo WHERE bar = :id");
$statement->bindValue('id', 1);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Doctrine creates some magic getters on your repository too, builded that way :  `findByColumneName(param)` or `findOneByColumnName(param)`